# Graphing a Line given x,y, and z angle

Tags: matlab

I have this piece of MATLAB code that outputs x,y, and z angles and I would like draw a line using them. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

```
C = pi;
A = pi;
B = pi;
Z = [cos(C),-sin(C),0; sin(C),cos(C),0; 0,0,1];
X = [1,0,0;0,cos(A),-sin(A);0,sin(A),cos(A)];
Y = [cos(B),0,sin(B);0,1,0;-sin(B),0,cos(B)];
R =(X*Y)*Z;
yaw=atan2(R(2,1),R(1,1))
pitch=atan2(-R(3,1),sqrt(R(3,2)^2+R(3,3)^2))
roll=atan2(R(3,2),R(3,3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X`, `Y`, and `Z` are not angles, they are rotation matrices defined by the angles `A`, `B`, and `C`.

it's not clear what's the meaning of "draw a line using them", they are just used to rotate vectors in the 3D space.

here is an example of drawing a rotated vector with them:

```
% define rotation angles (around the axes)
C = pi/2;
A = pi/4;
B = pi/4;
% generate rotation matrices
Z = [cos(C),-sin(C),0; sin(C),cos(C),0; 0,0,1];
X = [1,0,0;0,cos(A),-sin(A);0,sin(A),cos(A)];
Y = [cos(B),0,sin(B);0,1,0;-sin(B),0,cos(B)];
R =(X*Y)*Z;
% generate a vector and rotate it
v = [1;1;1];
u = R*v;
% plot
quiver3(0,0,0,v(1),v(2),v(3));
hold on
quiver3(0,0,0,u(1),u(2),u(3));
xlim([-1 1]); ylim([-1 1]); zlim([-1 1])
axis square
legend('original','rotated')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the explanation I was looking for. I apologize for my wording not being very clear.